# What is the operating temperarature of a scram jet at its theoretical maximum speed?

Tags: temperature, scramjet

What is the operating temperature of a scram jet at its theoretical maximum speed of Mach 24?

For those with access to a simulator and do such simulators exist and are they possible?

Given this speed is achievable and there are no known existing materials that can handle the temperatures, would ceramic shielding along with liquid cooling assisted by refrigeration technology suffice and is it feasible for both the engine and air frame?

Comment: Could you add a link or and explanation how the maximum speed is calculated? Is this based on the orbital speed? Given that the speed of sound varies with altitude (as does the orbital speed?!) the Mach number changes with altitude as well. Or is there another fluid-dynamics limit?

Comment: The most efficient operating altittude for a scramjet

Comment: ok, so let's say we would know _the_ most efficient altitude, how do we calculate the theoretical maximum speed?

Comment: between 70 and 75 km altitude maximum and Mach 24 maximum speed using hydrogen as fuel